# Django: How to retrieve a Queryset of the latest, uniquely named records with a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I require a query that can search my model for the latest, unique records and return a queryset of the results.

I need distinct on `setup_name` and latest on `updated`

**models.py**

```py
class VehicleSetupModel(models.Model):

    inertia = models.IntegerField()
    tyre_pressure = models.IntegerField()


class StandardVehicleSetupModel(VehicleSetupModel):

    setup_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**What I've tried**

I tried the following:

```
StandardVehicleSetupModel.objects.all().order_by('updated').distinct('setup_name')
```

but MySQL does not support `DISTINCT ON` querys.

**Table Layout** *(DD-MM-YYYY)*

```
     setup_name     |     updated      |      vehicle     
----------------------------------------------------------
        TEH              10-10-2020              1 
        TEH              11-10-2020              1
        TEL              10-10-2020              1
        TEL              08-10-2020              1
        TEL              01-10-2020              1
        TEP              01-10-2020              1
```

**Expected Result** *(DD-MM-YYYY)*

```
     setup_name     |     updated      |      vehicle     
----------------------------------------------------------
        TEH              11-10-2020              1
        TEL              10-10-2020              1
        TEP              01-10-2020              1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MySQL doesn't support `distinct()` with arguments. We can use another way:

```
from django.db.models import Max


results = (
    StandardVehicleSetupModel.objects
      .values('setup_name')
      .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
      .values_list('max_id', 'setup_name')
      .order_by('max_id')
)
```

Not tested yet, but it should work ^^